# What software supports variable-like code completion in XML documents?

Tags: xml, autocomplete, xsd, editor, intellisense

So, I work with an in-house XML solution we use for defining content, with it's own XSD file that goes with it. I want to be able to do Context Tagging and reference auto-complete like I do with C# and other languages for certain cases, while still using the XSD file for syntax validation. Example:

```
<Object id="foo" />
<Object id="bar" />
<Object id="myobject" source="foo" />
```

When I type in 'source=' in the third object, I want it to offer me up 'foo', 'bar', and any other ids on Objects in the file (or project, either way).  'foo' and 'bar' are not pre-defined strings in the XSD file; we have thousands of them and add more every day. So, when I declare a new XML node of

```
<Object id='someid'>
```

I want the next time I type 'source=' to prompt me with 'someid' in the list, just like how C#/C++ does with variables.

I'm willing to use any code editor/text editor/IDE, but if there is no way to do this, what editor would be easiest to add this to? From a programming point of view, this should really not be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

The XML Editor in Visual Studio has the features you seem to be after. This article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255811.aspx gives a nice overview.

Alternatively, while I've not used it personally this post [Using XML Schema for code autocomplete in my XML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958414/using-xml-schema-for-code-autocomplete-in-my-xml-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggests that similar features are available in Eclipse.

Or there is this project on github https://github.com/pleonex/atom-autocomplete-xml for Atom that looks like it might do what you want.

Comment: That's what I currently use and it's ok, but I wanted more. I suppose I wasn't quite clear enough in my question. 'foo' and 'bar' are not pre-defined strings in the XSD file; we have thousands of them and add more every day. So, when I declare a new XML node of <Object id='someid'> I want the next time I type <Object source= to prompt me with 'someid' in the list, just like how C#/C++ does with variables. MSVS XML Editor is not capable of what I'm after (and frankly is very pathetic compared to their C#/C++ Editors).

Comment: @Dreadicon Auto-completion is not going to suggest something which it cannot index, like your id field. What you can do in Netbeans is type `f` and press Ctrl+K and it will start suggesting the last word you typed beginning with `f`. You can expand this further by typing something like `Fooba` Ctrl+K and it will complete it to `Foobar` if that word was encountered before. Keep pressing Ctrl+K for words even older.